# Discord Bot using python sending multiple responses to one command

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a bot in python for discord using atom and whenever I run a command on my bot (including help) it sends multiple responses to the command, not all of the responses are the same (e.g: s?ping it will answer multiple times with different ping). I think the amount it sends is random and i'm not sure what's wrong with it at all, i've heard that looping does this but i only have one loop and that's to change the status. This is my code (without the token):

````py
import discord
import random
import os
from itertools import cycle
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 's?')
status = cycle(['s? // Senkuu by Rubix', 's?help - Made by Rubix#8166', 's? // Alpha v0.11.2, Made in Python (discord.py/atom)'])

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print( 'Bot is ready. ')

@tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def change_status ():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)} ms')

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error,commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Missing Requirements in Command, Try Again.')

@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ["It is certain.",
    "It is decidedly so.",
    "Without a doubt.",
    "Yes - definitely.",
    "You may rely on it.",
    "As I see it, yes.",
    "Most likely.",
    "Outlook good.",
    "Yes.",
    "Signs point to yes.",
    "Reply hazy, try again.",
    "Ask again later.",
    "Better not tell you now.",
    "Cannot predict now.",
    "Concentrate and ask again.",
    "Don't count on it.",
    "My reply is no.",
    "My sources say no.",
    "Outlook not so good.",
    "Very doubtful."]
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer; {random.choice(responses)}')

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator [Staff]')
async def purge(ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator [Staff]')
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Banned {member.mention}')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *, reason):
    server = ctx.message.server
    mention = user.mention
    id = user.id
    author = str(ctx.message.author)
    x = discord.utils.get(server.channels, name="criminal-records")
    kick_message = "**Type: Kick**\n**User:** " + user.name + "#" + user.discriminator +"(" + id + ")" \
                    + "(" + mention+")\n" \
            "**Reason:** " + reason +"\n" \
            "**Responsible Moderator: **" + author
    await self.bot.kick(user)
    await self.bot.send_message(x, kick_message)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator [Staff]')
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            return

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs. {extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs. {extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')```
````

This is what it's doing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cisk.png

Comment: Can you indent that properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the bot running multiple times smh (fixed days ago)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for it to loop the way it did. Do you have any pong commands in any of your cogs at all? I've corrected your indentation and run it no problem not experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I have no cogs at the moment, just the main bot file, the one in the post, and the only ping command is in there

Comment: Copy and paste the code from above and add your token see if it works ok, it's running fine my end when tested.

Comment: that's weird, still happening to me. What are you testing it on?

Comment: I'm using Visual studio code, I did remove
```
@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs. {extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs. {extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```
Since there is no cogs to load

Comment: would it matter that i'm using Atom to run it? would there be a difference?

Comment: There shouldn't be  a problem, (https://paste.pythondiscord.com/jexahuqofa.py) <- That's your code edited without cogs stuff and it's not looping on ping

Comment: Pasted it, still happening

Comment: just pasted it and ran the file in Visual Studio code, still happening -_-

Comment: Sorry I don't know what's going on and why it's looping when you use Ping